# How to read in a local JSON file for testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, sentestingkit

I'm trying to write unit tests for json validation (since the app heavily relies on json from a rest API).

I have a local file that contains simple json:  "goodFeaturedJson.txt"

The contents:

```
{
  "test": "TEST"
}
```

The test case:

```
- (void)testJsonIsValid
{
    Featured *featured = [Featured new];

    NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"goodFeaturedJson" ofType:@"text"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];//[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"The json string is: %@", jsonString);

    id JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    STAssertTrue([featured jsonIsValid:JSON], @"Featured Data is NOT valid...");    
}
```

The test fails every time.  The console prints:

```
The json string is: (null)
```

Why?  I know why the test is failing, since clearly if the data is nil/null there will be no valid json, and the validator will break (which it should if its invalid).

There must be something simple I missed here, any ideas?

Comment: should ofType be `ofType:@"txt"`?

Comment: The string is still null if I do that.  I've tried text, and "json" as the type.  The result seems to always be the same and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What does the error (that you apparently don't bother to check) say?

Comment: Is *data null as well?

Comment: The data parameter to JSONObjectWithData: is nil.  (which is the error).

Also yes, the NSData object is nil.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In a unit test you probably want to use `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`, and not `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. That's because the unit test is not a standalone app. With `mainBundle` you get something like `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools`, but using `bundleForClass` gets you the bundle where your unit test class is located.

```
guard let pathString = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "UnitTestData", ofType: "json") else {
    fatalError("UnitTestData.json not found")
}
```

Comment: Damn, didn't realize that about NSBundle; thanks!  (This solved everything).

Answer (score 26):

## In Swift

**Swift 5 and above**

```
guard let pathString = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "UnitTestData", ofType: "json") else {
    fatalError("UnitTestData.json not found")
}

guard let jsonString = try? String(contentsOfFile: pathString, encoding: .utf8) else {
    fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to String")
}

print("The JSON string is: \(jsonString)")

guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
    fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to Data")
}

guard let jsonDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String:Any] else {
    fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to JSON dictionary")
}

print("The JSON dictionary is: \(jsonDictionary)")
```

**Swift 3 and 4**

```
guard let pathString = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "UnitTestData", ofType: "json") else {
    fatalError("UnitTestData.json not found")
}

guard let jsonString = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: pathString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else {
    fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to String")
}

print("The JSON string is: \(jsonString)")

guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else {
    fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to NSData")
}

guard let jsonDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] else {
    fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to JSON dictionary")
}

print("The JSON dictionary is: \(jsonDictionary)")
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
    guard let pathString = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).pathForResource("UnitTestData", ofType: "json") else {
        fatalError("UnitTestData.json not found")
    }

    guard let jsonString = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: pathString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
        fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to String")
    }

    print("The JSON string is: \(jsonString)")

    guard let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
        fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to NSData")
    }

    guard let jsonDictionary = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] else {
        fatalError("Unable to convert UnitTestData.json to JSON dictionary")
    }

    print("The JSON dictionary is: \(jsonDictionary)")
```

*This incorporates Tom Harrington's answer which is in Objective C

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this bit: ` Bundle(for: type(of: self))` couldn't find that anywhere else and that made it work in Unit Tests!